# Есть ли подобная замена [attr*=value] из CSS в SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

Всем привет, в процессе изучения **SASS**. Возник вопрос.

Дано:

```
[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

хочется избавиться от `[class*='col-']`. точнее, хочу полностью перевести данную запись в **SASS**. Если такое нельзя реализовать, то как сделать в CSS по другом, без использования такого атрибута

Comment: Не меняя разметку -- никак. Других способов сделать частичное совпадение в CSS просто нет. И это уже валидный SCSS, не требующий дополнительных преобразований.

Comment: Ну, допустим я готов пойти на смену разметки. Мне хочется чтобы все элементы с классом col- были с заданными свойствами и запись была в SASS. Но сколько искал, не находил подобного

Comment: Вы не поняли. Изменение разметки нужно именно ради изменения селектора. Не хотите матчить атрибут -- используйте отдельный класс (не кусочек!) или признаки по иерархии.

Comment: Создайте любой класс с данными свойствами а потом подмешивайте его с помощью экстендов.

Comment: а не могли бы вы примерчик показать?